# Disable edit on certain columns in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I would like to disable certain columns in my JTable, I know how to disable them all, but this is not what I need. I Have 4 columns

The 'Accepted' column is a checkbox and I would like that to stay editable but the rest should not. Any ideas?

```
 |Name    | Address  | Phone  | Accepted |
 -----------------------------------------
  Bob       Random     45678    Yes
```

Thanks you :)

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

Answer (score 10):

I figured it out

```
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return column == 3;
```

Comment: Where do I put the method...?